# Google script doesn't send messages

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I wrote a google script code (to send specific emails) and it'd been working for a while. But then I stopped it for about a month ago, and now I need it again. The problem is that code is executed, but it doesn't send any message. Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code.

```
function sendEmailL() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Lb'); //Sheet name
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 30; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells U:V
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 30)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[20]; // First column
    var message = row[21]; // Second column
    var subject = 'Новое поступление от рекламодателя';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: if the code used to work but not it does not and you don't get any errors then most likely you changed the structure of your sheet. Share a screenshot of your sheet (remove sensitive information) so we can reproduce the problem. Look if you have changed the position of the data or the sheet name or stuff like that.

Comment: If range of sheet is fix in your case then use explicate funcation as
`var dataRange = sheet.getRange("U1:V30")`

Comment: Unfortunate, I can't add a picture here, but I have only two active columns: U with emails and V with text. So it used to work this way. And all of the rows since 1 till the end of the table. I don't understand why the code doesn't give an error if something goes wrong

Comment: Put a `console.log(data)` after you define `data` to see if you are getting any data at all. The reason you don't get any errors is because `for` loop is never executed, most likely because `data` does not have any data in it. It is always a good practice in any programming language to `log` the variables to see if they contain the expected data. Otherwise, you just coding in blind.

Comment: I get an error this way: Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient

Comment: guess what, you can also `console.log(emailAddress)` after `emailAddress` is defined. But again I guess the error has to do with either empty email or wrong email address.

Comment: Can you do a `Logger.log(emailAddress)` or a `console.log(emailAddress)` and then check on the execution logs to see if the address is actually there?

Answer (score 1):

If your not getting the right data in the dialog you need to learn how to use developer tools to figure out what's wrong.

```
function sendEmailL() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Lb'); //Sheet name
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 30; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells U:V
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 30)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  let html='Test Data:<br />';
  for (var i;i<data.length;i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[20]; // First column
    var message = row[21]; // Second column
    var subject = 'Новое поступление от рекламодателя';
    //MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />Row:%s-emal: %s subject: %s message: %s',i+startRow,emailAddress,subject,message)
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Testing');
}
```

And you probably should be checking `getRemainingDailyQuota()` to make sure you haven't exceeded the daily quota